# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security

Hi I try write a Spring Security application but i have a problem. I get error:

> ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userDetailsService' is defined

My pom.xml

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <groupId>pl.piotr</groupId>
>   <artifactId>ibank</artifactId>
>   <name>iBank</name>
>   <packaging>war</packaging>
>   <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
>   <properties>
>       <java-version>1.6</java-version>
>       <spring.security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
>       <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
>       <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
>       <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
>       <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
>   </properties>
>
>   <dependencies>
>       <!-- Spring -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>           <exclusions>
>               <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
>               <exclusion>
>                   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
>               </exclusion>
>           </exclusions>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Spring AOP + AspectJ -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
>           <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
>           <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Spring-tx -->
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Spring expressions -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Logging -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>           <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
>           <scope>runtime</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>           <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
>           <scope>runtime</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>log4j</groupId>
>           <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
>           <version>1.2.15</version>
>           <exclusions>
>               <exclusion>
>                   <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
>               </exclusion>
>               <exclusion>
>                   <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
>               </exclusion>
>               <exclusion>
>                   <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
>               </exclusion>
>               <exclusion>
>                   <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
>               </exclusion>
>           </exclusions>
>           <scope>runtime</scope>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- @Inject -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
>           <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
>           <version>1</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Servlet -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>           <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
>           <version>2.5</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
>           <version>2.1</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
>           <version>1.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Test -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>junit</groupId>
>           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>           <version>4.7</version>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Database -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
>           <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
>           <version>11.2.0.3</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
>           <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
>           <version>1.0</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Spring Security -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Hibernate -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>           <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
>           <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Validation -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
>           <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
>           <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
>           <type>jar</type>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
>           <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
>           <version>1.4</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>   </dependencies>
>
>   <build>
>       <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>               <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>2.9</version>
>               <configuration>
>                   <additionalProjectnatures>
>                       <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
>                   </additionalProjectnatures>
>                   <additionalBuildcommands>
>                       <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
>                   </additionalBuildcommands>
>                   <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
>                   <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>2.5.1</version>
>               <configuration>
>                   <source>1.6</source>
>                   <target>1.6</target>
>                   <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
>                   <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
>                   <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>               <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>1.2.1</version>
>               <configuration>
>                   <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>   </build>
> </project>
> ```

security-config.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.piotr.ibank" />

    <security:http>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/client**"
            access="ROLE_CLIENT" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin**"
            access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:form-login login-page='/login'
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
            default-target-url="/user" authentication-failure-url="/login?authfailed" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled" />

</beans>
```

implementation UserDetailsService

```
    package pl.piotr.ibank.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import pl.piotr.ibank.daointerface.UserDao;
import pl.piotr.ibank.model.UserRole;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        pl.piotr.ibank.model.User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user
                .getUserRole());

        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getName()));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(
                setAuths);

        return Result;
    }

    private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(
            pl.piotr.ibank.model.User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true,
                true, true, authorities);
    }

    public UserDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }
}
```

UserDaoImpl

```
    package pl.piotr.ibank.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import pl.piotr.ibank.daointerface.UserDao;
import pl.piotr.ibank.model.User;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {

        User user;
        user = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from User where username=?")
                .setParameter(0, username);

        return user;
    }
}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.piotr.ibank" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:HR" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="HR" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="asdfghj" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource">
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>pl.piotr.ibank.model.User
                </beans:value>
                <beans:value>pl.piotr.ibank.model.UserRole
                </beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                    true
                </beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml
        </param-value>

    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I edited my security-conifg.xml and userDetailService is ok, but i have new error:

> ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory pl.piotr.ibank.dao.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: All of your spring bean configurations for the data source is commented out, inc. your component scan for beans in packages.

Comment: Edit, bad paste. This cofiguration not commented in my app.

Comment: @blackpanther Actually it isn't that is just the highlighting of StackOverflow that is confused. Problem is the security configuration is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and the actual component-scanning is done in the `DispatcherServlet` the first cannot see beans in the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: @blackpanther That seems to be a bug in the component used to display the code... the code itself does not comment the configuration out.

Comment: Would like to see your web.xml with contextConfigLocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening here is when your application starts up it will load following first.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
    /WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Which means unless you have a `component-scan` to cover `MyUserDetailsService` in `root-context.xml` your UserDetailsService won't be available for `security-config.xml`, thus the bean not found exception is thrown.

You can either add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.piotr.ibank" />
```

to fix this.

**EDIT**

You are having a bean dependency nightmare. Organize your dependencies like the following.

create a new `db-config.xml` and have following

```
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.piotr.ibank.dao" />

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:HR" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="HR" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="asdfghj" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource">
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>pl.piotr.ibank.model.User
            </beans:value>
            <beans:value>pl.piotr.ibank.model.UserRole
            </beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                true
            </beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

and in your `root-context.xml` add the following;

```
<import resource="classpath:/WEB-INF/spring/db-config.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:/WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml"/>
```

and have the following `web.xml` config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        </param-value>

    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: Added `/WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml`   after `servlet-context.xml` but still the same error.

Comment: That doesn't change a thing your `ContextLoaderListener` will NEVER see the beans in your `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: I edited my security-conifg.xml and userDetailService is ok, but i have new error. Edited in first post.

Comment: Ok. But I find bad. I can't @Autowired SessionFactory in Dao class. I delete Autowired and it work's. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `security-config.xml` file:

```
<beans:import resource="servlet-context.xml" />
```